# Why are badges not sorted in the 'Select your next badge' modal window?

Tags: support, badges

I can see that this dialog selects `max` score and recommend this badge to me.

But also I have different badges with a high score, but they are laid somewhere in the list.

It would be good if this list is sorted by `score`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the suggested badge dialog is sorted by **percentage of both progress bars filled** instead of just score or number of answers.  I think this makes sense since tag badges require both score and number of answers.  This is especially helpful after you get a tag badge and the next tier of the tag badge is far off.

Here's a portion of my badge progress dialog:

> [image: Tag badge progress]

You can see the badges are sort left-to-right then row-by-row by the combined fill percentage:

- 100 + 45 = 145
- 100 + 45 = 145
- 100 + 40 = 140
- 83 + 55 = 138
- 100 + 35 = 135
- 70 + 65 = 135

Comment: For tied percentages, it looks from my experience like they're sorted alphabetically by the tag name.

Comment: Good. Even can not imagine this math. Would be good if percentage will be displayed for clarity

Comment: In this case, I just took the percentages by dividing out the requirements.  It's convenient in the examples above since there are 20 answers required, so each answer is 5%.